# NodeJs Download Mongoose document as a file

Tags: node.js, mongodb, csv

I'm trying to trigger a file download from a mongoose document lookup however, I can't seem to return the returned data as a file.

As you can see i'm transforming some json data returned from the DB into a CSV, and then trying to send it to the client as a file type text/csv.

The data doesn't seem to be generate a file attachment when the response is sent.

Any suggestions or pointers in the right direction would be appreciated.

```
exports.download = function (req, res, next) {
  var dataSetId = req.params.id;

  DataContentModel.findById(dataSetId, function (err, doc) {
    if (err) return next(err);
    if (!doc) return res.send({'error': 'This record was not found.'});

    var keys = [];
    for(var k in doc.data[0]) keys.push(k);

    json2csv({data: doc.data, fields: keys}, function (err, csv) {
      if (err) console.log(err);

      res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/csv');
      res.setHeader('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename=csv.csv');
      res.send(csv);

    });
  });

};
```

Comment: Need more information. Where exactly are things going wrong? Have you verified that the data is coming out of mongo correctly? Have you verified the csv conversion works? Is it just the download prompt that doesn't work? What happens when you try it?

Comment: @TimothyStrimple Hey, sorry, i thought my explanation was enough info. Yes, everything is working up into the res.send the output looks like a proper csv file, and is responding to the browser, but just as data, not as a file attachment.